# Browserify. TypeError: item.copy is not a function?

Tags: javascript, browserify, require

So I'm using Browserify to finally remove that pesky `TypeError: require is not defined` that I'd been trying to deal with for a while now. When I finally got it to work, this new error `TypeError: item.copy is not a function` is thrown instead.

Inside the bundled Browserify code, this is the block of code the error refers to:

```
var buf = new Buffer(length)
var pos = 0
for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
  var item = list[i]
  item.copy(buf, pos)
  pos += item.length
} return buf
```

I've never seen a `copy()` function for an array before, but I don't know why Browserify would have generated it if it didn't exist.

Anyone know what might cause this?